# Module not found.Can't resolve '../firebase/config'

Tags: reactjs, firebase, module

[Project Directory image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSXqY.png)

I am trying to import firebase in my react app, using the following syntax:

import {auth} from '../firebase/config

But I am facing following issue:

./src/Pages/Login/Login.js
Module not found: Can't resolve '../firebase/config'

this is my config file

import * as firebase from '/firebase/app'
import 'firebase/auth';
import 'firebase/firestore'

//  Firebase configuration
const firebaseConfig = {
apiKey: "*****",
authDomain: "******",
projectId: "*****",
storageBucket: "*****",
messagingSenderId: "*****",
appId: "*******"
};

// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const firestore =firestore.firestore();
const auth = firebase.auth();

export { auth, firestore };

thanks for your help in advance

Comment: Please share a screenshot of your directory structure.

Comment: Hi, please find attached project directory image.Thanks!

Comment: Hello, if my answer was useful you can accept (✔) and upvote () it. Feel free to ask further questions.

Answer (score 0):

Your path is incorrect. `'../firebase/config'` will look for the config file in `src/Pages/firebase` but the config is present in `src/firebase`.  Try this path instead:

```js
import {auth} from '../../firebase/config'
//                  ^^
```

Comment: I tried doing it also.But it throws me this error. You attempted to import ../../firebase/config which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.

Comment: @Archana I doubt if this error is coming from a different file then.